# requests.get does not response in python?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, python-requests

I have the following script which I tried to get response status from `request.get(url)`

```
from flask import *

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/welcome')
    print r
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/welcome')
def wecome():

    print "welcome page"

    return "welcome to my page"


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I access endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` the browser keeps spinning none stop without any output result in terminal console as I expected even the error message.

However, if I change the requests url to something else externally as below, the response is showing up the status `<Response [200]>` in terminal and the page is loaded as normal.

```
from flask import *

import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/emojis')
    print r
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/welcome')
def wecome():

    print "welcome page"

    return "welcome to my page"


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

what's going on with that?

 How can I get response from internal url as I need it badly for my current work?

Comment: just call `welcome()`

Comment: P.S.: It doesn't work because you are in debug and there's only a single worker in your "server", thus blocking the request.

Comment: @AArias thanks, by using `welcome()` it print the output fine, how can know the status of request if the request to my url is successful or not. Does that mean if I disable debug it will work?

Comment: If you use the built-in server it won't work. You need a proper server with several workers for this code to actually work. Search "flask gunicorn nginx". If you had at least two workers it would work.

Comment: How can I check worker on my machine? does that mean flask gunicorn nginx support several worker?

Comment: gunicorn and nginx is a common combination of server and reverse proxy to deploy flask apps. Is what you want when deploying an app to production (that is, you want to handle more than one request at the same time). With your current, dev setup, you can only handle one request at a time, that's why you can't make a request to your own server while already handling another request. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: @AArias, Thanks much, I got the point.

Comment: No problem. Check this page for different deployment alternatives: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/

Comment: @AArias, thanks very much for your guideline. Finally, I got it working by using `gunicorn` `gunicorn --workers 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app` and following instruction to setup from here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 . This new knowledge I've never known. ;)